# Error en instalación de SQLserver 2019 express, Error de datos

Tags: sql-server, instalacion

Resulta que me encuentro realizando la instalación de SQLserver Express, tras realizar todos los pasos del proceso de instalación (escogí instalación personalizada, por recomendación del curso que estoy realizando) y prácticamente al finalizar la instalación me sale en pantalla el siguiente mensaje: Error de datos (comprobación de redundancia cíclica)

Tras consultar un poco decidí eliminar y desinstalar todos los archivos referentes a SQLserver y posteriormente tratar de volver a instalar el programa, con la desgracia de que vuelvo a obtener el mismo problema, consulte en foros de Microsoft pero no halle una solución exacta al mismo problema, por lo que recurro a ustedes en busca de ayuda.

PD: además de lo dicho anteriormente, antes de instalar la versión express del programa instale la versión de desarrollador y realice el proceso de instalación de la misma, pero al no encontrar la opción de descargar la dependencia "LocalDB" decidí desistir de esta versión e instalar la versión express (como dije anteriormente, recomendada por el curso) tengo la idea de que quizás el problema de instalación radica allí pero no he encontrado una solución al mismo.

[image: Error mostrado por el Setup de SQLserver]

Comment: Los errores de CRC se dan porque el instalador no descargó bien. COnfirma que tu antivirus no está haciendo locuras y borrando cosas o bloqueando cosas.

Comment: @Alfabravo Pues, como tal solo cuento con el antivirus de Windows (por defecto), Trate ya de reparar las dependencias pero ninguna lo logro, puede que si sean por el instalador pero, en caso de que no sea por lo mismo, ¿sabes que mas podría hacer?

Comment: Prueba ejecutando el instalador como Administrador :/ estás sobre Windows10?

Comment: @Alfabravo Dale, pues, realizare la desinstalación del programa y ejecutándolo como Admin, y si, uso Windows 10